# Can't decode received JSON to array

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, post

**The JS**

Serializing data from a FORM, stringify it and POST it as JSON with AJAX to update.php

```
jQuery.fn.serializeObject = function () {
  var formData = {};
  var formArray = this.serializeArray();

  for(var i = 0, n = formArray.length; i < n; ++i)
    formData[formArray[i].name] = formArray[i].value;

  return formData;
};

$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        data = $('form').serializeObject();
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));   
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'inc/update.php',
            data: {json: JSON.stringify(data)},
            dataType: 'json'
        });  
    });
});
```

**The `update.php` file where it should be decoded to an array**

```
$str_json = file_get_contents('php://input'); //($_POST doesn't work here)
$response = json_decode($str_json, true); // decoding received JSON to array

$name = $response['name'];

$update = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE user SET name='".$name."' WHERE id='3';");
$update->execute();//the SQL works fine with String for $name
```

**With Tamper Data addon in Firefox i checked the POSTDATA, here it is:**

```
json=%7B%22name%22%3A%22fff%22%7D
```

This is like:

```
json={"name":"fff"}
```

I'm new at JS/AJAX/JSON and I cant find my mistake. So please help me. 
I've searched for many hours without success.

Comment: 2nd decode parameter = true

Comment: -I've tried $name = $response['name']; but doesnt Work :-(
-2nd decode parameter is already true

Comment: I only meant to point out that you had set ur 2nd argument as true

Comment: Now i've understood, thank you :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know what's the point of writing `serializeObject` function, when you can just use `serializeArray`.

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Stop normal submission, which is probably why your PHP code isn't working
        data = $('form').serializeArray();
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));   
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'inc/update.php',
            data: {
                json: JSON.stringify(data)
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });  
    });
    return false;
});
```

PHP:

```
$str_json = _$_POST['json'];
$response = json_decode($str_json, true); // decoding received JSON to array
$name = $response['name'];
```

If you use `true` as 2nd argument in `json_decode` it returns an array not object.
So you need to do

```
$name = $response['name'];
```

Comment: I've Exchanged my Code against these Code. I didn't knew serializeArray. the posted json looks now like [{"name":"name","value":"testvalue"}]. But i cant decode it.

Comment: @Luk4s `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on top of your php file, then check response.

Comment: alert(xhr.status);//200
alert(thrownError);//SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 3

Comment: @Luk4s Is the query updating the row in table? Are you echoing JSON at the end of PHP script?

Answer (score 0):

**I found the Problem with our Help: The JSON-String was not correct**

Explained step by step:

```
$str_json = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $str_json;//json%3D%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22Max%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22testvalue%22%7D%5D

$str_json = urldecode($str_json);
echo $str_json;//json=[{"name":"Max","value":"testvalue"}]

$str_json = str_replace('json=', '', $str_json);
echo $str_json;//[{"name":"Max","value":"testvalue"}]

//now it is a json-string which can be json_decoded
$arr_json = json_decode($str_json, true);
$name = $arr_json['name'];
echo $name;//Max
```

Thanks a lot guys!